# How to call comparator function from sort in C++ class

Tags: c++, sorting, oop

Inside the `isAlienSorted` function object, I am calling customized sort to sort the list of strings in lexicographical order. Due to the given alphabetical order may vary (not always follow abcd...), the customized sort needs to call cmp to sort the list of strings in correct order. How to call the cmp function in this case.

I also tried another way to make cmp as a struct object, but because mapping is a private vector, I am confused how to call the mapping inside the cmp object.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
private:
  vector<int> mapping;

public:
  bool cmp(string w1, string w2) {
    int w1_len = w1.size();
    int w2_len = w2.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < min(w1_len,w2_len); i++) {
      if (mapping[w1[i]] > mapping[w2[i]]) return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  bool isAlienSorted(vector<string>& word, string order) {
    int order_len = order.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < order_len; i++) {
      mapping[order[i]] = i;
    }

    vector<string> sorted = word;
    sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), cmp);

    if (word == sorted) return true;
    else return false;
  }
};
```

I am very confused, but I hope I express the problem clear.

Following is the error log:

```
solution.cpp: In member function isAlienSorted
Line 28: Char 43: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'bool Solution::cmp(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)'
     sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), cmp);
                                           ^
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate.  Make your comparison function `static` or use a lambda function.

Comment: the mapping member prevents the static way.

Comment: Also, there is a [std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) function.  There is no need to sort the entire container to determine if the items are sorted.  Thus the bulk of all of this is `return std::is_sorted(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), cmp);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the lambda function works. if I am trying to make the function `static`, it will give me the error `invalid use of member 'Solution::mapping' in static member function`. are there any ways to solve it?

Comment: You have to redesign your code to use the `static`, since `mapping` is not static.  Also, going back to `is_sorted`, you don't even need to make a copy of the vector.  Just `return std::is_sorted(word.begin(), word.end(), cmp);`

Comment: The closest duplicate I found was [invalid use of non-static member function in qsort C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581664/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-in-qsort-c), but that lacks the complication that the function in question cannot be made `static`.

Comment: Notice that you `cmp` function breaks [strict weak order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order), we have both `cmp("a", "ab")`, `cmp("ab", "a")` and so with transitivity, we should have `cmp("a", "a")` but we should have `!cmp("a", "a")` (that we have). So you break at least transitivity.

Answer (score 4):

Using a lambda is one way:

```
sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), [this](string& w1, string& w2){return cmp(w1, w2);});
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort()` does not allow you to use a non-static class method for its predicate. So you will have to call `cmp()` from inside a lambda (C++11 and later) or functor (pre-C++11) which has access to the `this` pointer of the `Solution` object that `isAlienSorted()` is being called on.

Comment: it uses this to access `mapping`